# No provider for Camera-Injection-Error (with provider in Module.ts) in Ionic Angular

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, mobile

im trying to make an app with ionic-angular using ionic/ngx  camera, but I keep getting this error in spite of adding the camera provider in the module.ts section.

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3KZz.png)

And this is my module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';


    import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

    import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
    import {AuthGuardService} from './services/auth-guard.service';
    import {AuthenticationService} from './services/authentication.service';
    import {Storage} from '@ionic/Storage';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { QRCodeModule } from 'angularx-qrcode';
    **import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';**


    @NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [ BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),                         QRCodeModule],
    providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }, **Camera**],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

The method im trying to pull of is this one

```
 export class PhotoService{
  constructor(private camera: Camera){}




    takePicture(){
      const fotito = Image;
      const options: CameraOptions ={
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      }


    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {imageData= fotito

    },(err) =>{console.log('Problemas de camara' + err);

  })
  return(fotito);
 }
}
```

Comment: Photo service is not in this module.

Comment: And why it should be? PhotoService is in service.ts, it uses Camera

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the Camera in the module that uses the camera plugin, You have it place incorrectly in the app.component, move it to the component that uses the camera.

Comment: I did, but the error persists